# Test driven development - mock object

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I'm trying to develop my first project using TDD. In this case I have to write test case before the code of my application. In my test case i have some mock object. I want to know if the expectations of the mock object must be written also before the code creation. If it is true, how can I achieve this objective? How can I imagine the method that must be call before i write the true code? (I'm using Java with JUnit and Jmock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly how TDD works. You write a test based on your specifications: what do you want the class under test to do with its dependency (the mock object). When written, you make it compile by adding the method on the interface that you're mocking (default implementation returns nothing). And you can then make your unit-test (that uses the mock) pass. When all your tests are passing, then you can proceed to add unit-tests for the dependency, which will in turn drive the implementation of the empty methods you wrote in the step above.

It will ensure you have 100% coverage for all your concrete classes.

Answer (score 2):

That's why TDD is a *design* methodology at first place. With tests you are *designing* your application. You are creating nice API and then you are implementing this API by writing code which satisfies your design (i.e. meets requirements).

When you start from test, it helps you to understand requirements for your code and write down these requirements in form of assertions (btw someone else can implement these requirements). You will not create best design ever from start. But your design will evolve during refactoring - you will rename methods and classes, you will extract some code. And that will require tests changing - you will need to mock extracted dependencies. But your code will meet requirements at any time, because assertions will stay same.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if the expectations of the mock object must be written
>   also before the code creation

You can create a method that does nothing, and then mock the result.

> How can I imagine the method that must be call before I write the true
>   code?

How can you write the code without knowing what it has to do? Just start with empty methods...